# How to use page specific javascript using the starter-blog template using asset rev plugin?

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing with [starter-blog template](https://github.com/craftcms/starter-blog).

How do I include a page specific javascript using the asset rev plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `rev` function provided by the plugin to get the path to your JS file (relative to the asset base path) and register it with the `{% js %}` tag:

```twig
{% js rev('js/foobar.js') at head with { defer: true } %}
```

Another option that I like to use is to declare a block in the base template and then extend it the page specific template:

```twig
{# templates/_private/layout/index.html #}
{% block assets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ rev('main.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
```

```twig
{# templates/_private/your-page.html #}
{% extends '_private/layout/index.html' %}

{% block assets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ rev('js/foobar.js') }}" defer>
{% endblock %}
```